# How creat a circle in meter unit, at GCS_WGS_1984 coordinate?

Tags: units

My shapefile coordinate sysytem is GCS_WGS_1984.
I use the editor tool to draw a circle.
EX:Right click to enter the radius in 100 meters.
The unit seems to be degree.
I want draw a circle which unit is in meters.

Comment: Please state which software you're working with.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees

Comment: If you're using ArcGIS, look in the help for geodetic features.